# log4j2 Migration for property loading

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

I'm having a problem to print the log files after updating the log4 jars. Here is my implementation below. for the old version of log4j we only use the "PropertyConfigurator" for our logf4.properties (this is an external file). Im not sure if I missed something to declare but upon testing logs still not printing. The log4j version that im currently using now is the 2.17.2

```
private LoggerConfig (){
    try {

        //PropertyConfigurator.configureAndWatch(Constants.LOG_CONFIG);
        LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
        File file = new File(Constants.LOG_CONFIG);
        
        ConfigurationSource source = new ConfigurationSource(new FileInputStream(Constants.LOG_CONFIG), new File(Constants.LOG_CONFIG));
        Configurator.initialize(null, source);
        
        
        LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(this.getClass());
        LoggerContext.getContext().setConfigLocation(file.toURI());
        LOGGER.debug("Log4j Properties successfully loaded.");      
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Unable to load application properties file: " + Constants.LOG_CONFIG);
    }
    
    LOGGER.debug("Connection pool successfully initialized.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using mostly LOGGER.debug, the logging level is set to DEBUG or lower?
if is set to a higher level please consider setting it to a level lower to debug or trace to validate the  logf4.properties is proper linked